# I am getting error in below line. How can correct it? or have i implemented wrong way?

Tags: c, networking

I am making chat-server program. I want to check my currentUser is not null then it will work. but it gives me error.

error: invalid operands to binary != (have ‘User {aka struct User}’ and ‘void *’)
     if(currentUser != NULL)

i expect that "if condition" should be correct.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly indicates what's wrong: `currentUser` is of type `struct User`, but in order to compare it to `NULL`, it should be a pointer type (i.e. `struct User*`).

Comment: i got another problem. here below is my code
// code...

User* currentUser = getCurrentUser();
User actUser = currentUser;
if(currentUser != NULL){
    while(currentUser != actUser){
  sendServer2Client_TextMsg(currentUser->sock, buffer);
  actUser = actUser->next;
  } 
}
//end code
in while loop, currentUser doesn't compare with actUser. where am I getting problem?

Comment: shouldnt actUser be of type pointer i.e  User* actUser = currentUser ??